# Messenger chatbot not responding

Tags: messenger, facebook-chatbot

We've built a Messenger chatbot but it's not responding to messages.
It's connected to DialogFlow, but we think that the issue may be that the page is ineligible for a username for some reason.

Does anyone have any insight into such issues?

Comment: Without looking code how someone knows what is the issue?

Comment: Thanks @gretal, I think it might be more of an account rules issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.